# laravel - Use one GET parameter in route, but pass the rest to the url in view

Tags: php, forms, laravel, get, laravel-5

I have a route like this:

```
Route::get('/s', 'DashboardController@search');
```

A super simple function to open a view like this:

```
public function search() {
    return view('search');
}
```

And a form like this:

```
<form action="/s" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Where" required>
    <input type="text" id="checkin" placeholder="Check in" class="datepicker" required>
    <input type="text" id="checkout" placeholder="Check out" class="datepicker" required>
    <input type="submit" value="search now">
</form>
```

At the moment it sends the parameters through happily with the url like so:

```
http://localhost/s?location=Location%2C+Name%2C+Here&checkin=21-03-2016&checkout=22-03-2016
```

However, what I would really, really like to see in my URL is the following:

```
http://localhost/s/Location_Name_Here?checkin=21-03-2016&checkout=22-03-2016
```

Now I'm aware that I will have to modify the location myself to get it to read n a pretty manner like that. But how would I make it so that I end up using the location which is a parameter in the form, as a route, whilst still successfully passing the check in and check out parameters to the page in the traditional GET= fashion? I really want to keep that. I know I can do away with it entirely and just manipulate on the back end, but I'd rather not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting my own solution to help others. Not sure if there's a way to do it via laravel. So instead I created an event listener for the form itself, a click (not a submit listener or it'll loop).

Gave my submit button and form an ID:

```
<form action="/s" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Where" required>
    <input type="text" id="checkin" placeholder="Check in" class="datepicker" required>
    <input type="text" id="checkout" placeholder="Check out" class="datepicker" required>
    <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="search now">
</form>
```

Then the listener:

```
$('#submit-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var location = $('[name="location"]').val();
    //Console log to see it, and re-write it as necessary
    console.log(location);
    //Action attribute is changed to suit, and then it submits properly
    $('#form-id').attr('action', "/s/" + location).submit();
});
```

Now it works :)